# Flutter : save image in gallery

Tags: android, flutter, local-storage, android-permissions, image-gallery

I wish to store images in the gallery. However, this functionality only seems to work during debugging when I build the APK and test it on my phone. Once I install the APK without debugging, the image-saving feature no longer functions. It's important to note that I already have the necessary permissions to access local storage.[The permissions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CL8B7.jpg)

I tested it on two versions of Android 12 and 13

```
var image = await boundary.toImage();
    var byteData = await image.toByteData(format: ui.ImageByteFormat.png);
    var ref = FFAppState().FrameRef;
    final name = 'cl1box1_' + ref;
    await ImageGallerySaver.saveImage(byteData!.buffer.asUint8List(),
        name: name);
```

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/media_scanner

Answer (score 0):

Try this

use this below plugin

1. [device_info_plus: ^9.0.2](https://pub.dev/packages/device_info_plus)
2. [permission_handler: ^10.4.3](https://pub.dev/packages/permission_handler)
3. [image_gallery_saver: ^2.0.3](https://pub.dev/packages/image_gallery_saver)

   ```
   saveImage() async {
   PermissionStatus result;
   if (Platform.isAndroid) {
     DeviceInfoPlugin deviceInfo = DeviceInfoPlugin();
     AndroidDeviceInfo androidInfo = await deviceInfo.androidInfo;
     if (androidInfo.version.sdkInt >= 33) {
       result = await Permission.photos.request();
     } else {
       result = await Permission.storage.request();
     }
   if (result.isGranted) {

   var image = await boundary.toImage();
   var byteData = await image.toByteData(format: ui.ImageByteFormat.png);
   var ref = FFAppState().FrameRef;
   final name = 'cl1box1_' + ref;
   await ImageGallerySaver.saveImage(byteData!.buffer.asUint8List(),
       name: name);
     }

   } else {
     await openAppSettings();
   }
    }
   ```

add this code on **AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_VIDEO"/>
```